# Could not connect to the database mytable: could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I had the **php version 5 but now i upgraded to php 7** and i am getting problems that a didn't had with the older version.

One that i'm still trying to solve is this:

`Could not connect to the database mydatabase :could not find driver` (this appear when i run my script).

I tryed to open phpmyadmin and also appeared an error:

```
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
```

After a lot of search i still can find a solution, is this related to the version of my mysql on xampp? It need to be upgraded too?

Apache version: 2.4
mysqlnd 5.0.12

********************** EDIT*****************
Here is the code that makes the connection to database:

```
    function connection()
{
    $host = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'mydatabase';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;", $username, $password);
        $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

        // echo "Connected to $dbname at $host successfully.";

    }

    catch(PDOException $pe) {
        die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
        echo "Line: " . __LINE__;
    }

    return $conn;
} //connection
```

Answer (score 0):

Either install the mysqli driver on your server or use PDO, if that's available. Use this code to find out more information about the installed drivers:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

Comment: It appears: PDO drivers -> no values  ... could you please explain me how can i install it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your php.ini file and uncomment this line

```
extension=mysqli
```

Then restart your local server

Comment: it appears this ";   extension=mysqli" , it's just remove the ";" to uncomment?

Comment: i've changed and restarted xampp but still appearing the error

Comment: don't forget to restart the server :)

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to connect to the database plase?

Comment: @TOH19 yes, i posted now

Comment: @KevinRodriguez are you using linux or windows?

Comment: @TOH19 windows... i've solved the problem it was on php.ini, i needed to uncomment some extensions

Answer (score 0):

This was how i solved the problem:

**1º rename** *php.ini-developer* to *php.ini*

**2º add extensions**:

```
extension_dir = "D:\Programs\xampp\php\ext"
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=mbstring
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

**Working like a charm now!**